# What happens when kubernetes readiness-probe return false? How long to wait?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, readinessprobe

What happens when Kubernetes `readiness-probe` returns false? Does Kubernetes restart that pod after timeout? How long Kubernetes waits for readiness?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Readiness probe doesn't restart the pod/container, readiness probe determines that the container is ready to serve traffic. If the container is probed and considered not "ready", the container will be removed from the endpoints and traffic wont be sent to it, until it is ready again.

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes

[2] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes

[3] `kubectl explain pod.spec.containers.readinessProbe`

```
KIND:     Pod
VERSION:  v1

RESOURCE: readinessProbe <Object>

DESCRIPTION:
     Periodic probe of container service readiness. Container will be removed
     from service endpoints if the probe fails. Cannot be updated. More info:
     https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle#container-probes

     Probe describes a health check to be performed against a container to
     determine whether it is alive or ready to receive traffic.

FIELDS:
   exec <Object>
     One and only one of the following should be specified. Exec specifies the
     action to take.

   failureThreshold <integer>
     Minimum consecutive failures for the probe to be considered failed after
     having succeeded. Defaults to 3. Minimum value is 1.

   httpGet  <Object>
     HTTPGet specifies the http request to perform.

   initialDelaySeconds  <integer>
     Number of seconds after the container has started before liveness probes
     are initiated. More info:
     https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle#container-probes

   periodSeconds    <integer>
     How often (in seconds) to perform the probe. Default to 10 seconds. Minimum
     value is 1.

   successThreshold <integer>
     Minimum consecutive successes for the probe to be considered successful
     after having failed. Defaults to 1. Must be 1 for liveness and startup.
     Minimum value is 1.

   tcpSocket    <Object>
     TCPSocket specifies an action involving a TCP port. TCP hooks not yet
     supported

   timeoutSeconds   <integer>
     Number of seconds after which the probe times out. Defaults to 1 second.
     Minimum value is 1. More info:
     https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle#container-probes
```

Let's use the default readiness probe from the documentation:

```
cat pod.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.14.2
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    readinessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - cat
        - /tmp/healthy
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 5
```

To perform a probe, the kubelet executes the command cat /tmp/healthy in the target container. If the command succeeds, it returns 0, then the container is ready and can "serve". if the command returns anything but 0, container is not healthy.

Since this file doesn't exist in the container from the start, when the pod starts, it is going to be very unhealthy.

```
date && k get pods nginx
Thu  2 Dec 2021 19:08:43 AST
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx   0/1     Running   0          66s
```

now, lets exec into it and create the file, so that the command succeeds.

```
k exec -it nginx -- bash
root@nginx:/# touch /tmp/healthy
root@nginx:/# exit
exit
```

checking again:

```
date && k get pods nginx
Thu  2 Dec 2021 19:09:26 AST
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx   1/1     Running   0          110s
```

removing again:

```
k exec -it nginx -- bash
root@nginx:/# rm /tmp/healthy
root@nginx:/# exit
exit
```

checking:

```
date && k get pods nginx
Thu  2 Dec 2021 19:09:53 AST
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx   0/1     Running   0          2m17s
```

Comment: `until it is ready again` AFAIK a pod is ready on start, then live and checked by liveness-probes. Then can die and restart. So no such thing as `ready again` isn't it? (it would be as born again i.e. impossible)

Comment: Hi! The container can totally be `not ready` on start and it is important to understand that dying and restarting is not what happens to it within the context of the `readiness probe` (this is what we need `liveness probe` for). Container can become not ready and then ready again. Nothing is impossible :)

Comment: I've updated the answer to show the example of how the same container can be created unhealthy, then become healthy, and then turns unhealthy again.

Comment: I mean the cycle is: `not ready` ->`ready`->`live`->`died`. Can you clarify where and how could happen `ready again`  here?

Comment: Sure, the readiness probe is all about readiness to serve, so if at certain point in its lifetime the container is detected to be not ready, but then readiness probes succeed again - this is exactly when it is going to become ready again.

Comment: Do you mean after pod is `live` the readiness probe still try to check if it ready? And is it possible to be `live` but `not ready` ? And then `ready` again?

Comment: Correct, readiness probe is not just a one-time thing that happens during the container startup, it is a periodic event through its entire life cycle. From the [document, I linked above](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes): Note: Readiness probes runs on the container during its whole lifecycle.

Comment: Ok, clear, and what happens if a pod is live but not ready permanently? e.g. `not ready` ->`ready`->`live`->`not ready but live`->`not ready but live`->`not ready but live`->`not ready but live`->`not ready but live`...? Will it be restarted?

Comment: If the container is live and is not ready permanently - it is going to be not serving traffic permanently, no restarts.

Comment: Brilliant answer. I did tests on my own side and I can confirm the similar results.